# Download link not working on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Hi I am getting an error on IE

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this action
```

This is the code which is failing on IE but working fine on other browsers.

```
 var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.download = 'file';
            link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
```

The problem is on the `link.dispatchEvent` line.

Can anyone please help me to get it working?

Comment: MouseEvent doesn't work in IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent 
https://caniuse.com/#search=mouse%20event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The older versions of IE only supports an proprietary equivalent EventTarget.fireEvent() method and therefore consider using [HTMLElement.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) which is [fully supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click#Browser_compatibility) by all IE versions.